# LinkedList head node keeps being overwritten C

Tags: c, pointers

I am currently trying to create a linked list, however, for some reason, my head pointer data keeps being overwritten. I have the following method that is supposed to handle insertions into the table and record the frequency of any word that I have come across. If the word has already been seen, then update its frequency, otherwise, add the word to the end of the list with a frequency of 1. The print statement at the beginning of the method is supposed to print the word stored at the first value. The text I am using to test the list is `a dog and cat`, however the first print statement prints out the value stored in the `word` variable, even though it should always be printing out `a`. When I print the entire linked list, all I see is the last word entered, or `dog`. I am assuming it has something to do with the way I am iterating through the list to see if the word exists or if I have to print, but I cannot figure out how to go around that.

```
typedef struct tableNode{
  int freq;
  char * word;
  struct tableNode *next;

}tableNode;

void insertIntoTable(char* word){
    if (tableHead != NULL) printf("%s\n", tableHead -> word);
    if (tableHead == NULL){
        printf("Null %s\n", word);
        tableHead = (tableNode*) malloc(sizeof(tableNode));
        tableHead -> word = word;
        tableHead -> freq = 1;
        tableHead -> next = NULL;
        return;
    }

    tableNode* ptr = tableHead;
    while(ptr -> next != NULL){
        if (strcmp(ptr -> word, word) == 0){
            printf("Dup %s %s\n", ptr -> word, word);
            ptr -> freq = (ptr -> freq) + 1;
            return;
        }
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
    if (strcmp(ptr -> word, word) == 0){
        printf("Dup %s %s\n", ptr -> word, word);
        ptr -> freq = (ptr -> freq) + 1;
        return;
    }
    printf("New %s\n", word);
    ptr -> next = (tableNode*) malloc(sizeof(tableNode));
    ptr -> next -> word = word;
    ptr -> next -> freq = 1;
    ptr -> next -> next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it wasn't an issue with my method, it was an issue with how I was calling the insertion method. I was sending a char*, but the value of that char* kept changing, effectively changing the value of the head node every time. I created a duplicate with `strdup`and sent that value, at it worked.

Comment: Alternatively, the insert code could make a copy of the word it is given to store.  Making sure you know which code is responsible for which memory is very important in C.  Don't forget to free the copied word when freeing up your linked list.

Comment: That's true, thanks a lot! Probably would've slipped my mind if you hadn't mentioned it!